# Node post message with large body (1.3 mb) error : 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

with fiddler Im creating post message with header

**content-Type application/text-enriched**

```
app.post('/books',function(req,res){
        var writeStream  = fs.createWriteStream('C://Books.txt' ,{ flags : 'w' });
        writeStream.write(req.body)
```

I was able to stops in debug in var writestream but when i excute this line I got error `Entity is too large`

there is some technique to overcome this problem? I wanted just to send large 
text file...

after reading some posts I've added the following which doesnt help...

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.use( bodyParser.json({limit: '2mb'}) );       
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     
        extended: true,
        keepExtensions: true,
        limit: '2mb', 
        defer: true 
    }));
```

**UPDATE**

I've also tried with the following

```
  app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/text-enriched' }));
    app.use( bodyParser.raw({limit: '10mb'}) );
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     
        extended: true,
        keepExtensions: true,
        limit: '10mb', 
        defer: true
    }));
```

also got the same error...**413 Request Entity Too Large**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [body-parser documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), you have to configure it regarding the content-type of your request. In your case, something like

```
app.use( bodyParser.raw({limit: '1mb'}) );
```

or may be text

```
app.use( bodyParser.text({
    type : 'application/text-enriched', 
    limit: '1mb'
}) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the support please see my updated post I've tried what you suggest but got the same error,any other idea? my program is so simple I jsut want to read some file content (large file) and store it in txt file

Comment: and using only `app.use(  bodyParser.text({type : 'application/text-enriched', limit: '10mb'}) `

Comment: krampstudio This is the answer,thanks you are great its awesome!